# InputObject Pipe to Cmdlet - CM-RemoveDevice

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm writing this section of a migration script:

```
$devnames = Get-CMDevice -Name ($Site + "CSP*") | Remove-CMDevice
```

I get this error:

```
The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either
because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ([SecurityVerbs(..."USER1";
```

Looking at the help, it looks at though this cmdlet can only accept input by InputObject

```
-InputObject
Specifies a device object. To obtain a device object, use the Get-CMDevice cmdlet.

Type:   IResultObject
Position:   0
Default value:  None


Accept pipeline input:  True (ByValue)
Accept wildcard characters: False
-Name
Specifies the name of a device.

Type:   String
Aliases:    DeviceName
Position:   0
Default value:  None
Accept pipeline input:  False
Accept wildcard characters: False
```

I then tried this:

```
$Site = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter 3 Letter Site Code"
$devnames = Get-CMDevice -Name ($Site + "*")

foreach ($device in $devicenames) { Remove-CMDevice $device }
```

I can see that, maybe I need to somehow convert the devices on the first part of the pipeline to an input object 'value'? I thought they were unless I used `| Select Name` etc. so, am confused as to this last step. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The target cmdlet doesn't seem to accept pipeline input by property name, just by value, so I would try expanding the `Name` property of the input objects: `(Get-CMDevice -Name ($Site + "CSP*")).Name | Remove-CMDevice`

Comment: That doesn't work for me unfortunately @Ansgar The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (DEV01:PSObject) [Remove-CMDevice], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.Collections.Commands.RemoveDeviceCommand

Comment: Then you're most likely stuck with having to use a loop, e.g.: `Get-CMDevice -Name ($Site + "CSP*") | ForEach-Object { Remove-CMDevice $_ }`. I'm not sure why this is required in some cases, but I've had situations where a cmdlet according to the documentation *should* have accepted pipeline input, but didn't.

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers Just FYI (cannot test atm) regarding the by value theory and name. Names (of devices and many other objects) are not unique in SCCM so it would not be a safe method. Id would be unique so maybe that's what needed.

Comment: Tried to verify my assumption that Id is needed but as of SCCM 1802 this seems to be fixed. The original pipe just works now as it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked - Credit to @Ansgar

```
 $devicenames = (Get-CMDevice -Name ($Site + "CSP*")).Name
    ForEach ($device in $devicenames) 
    { Remove-CMDevice -DeviceName $Device -Force }
```

Comment: Surprised this doesn't work $Site = "ABC"
$csv = Import-Csv "C:csv.csv"
foreach ($line in $csv) { 
                        
                        Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $line.Name | Where-Object {
                        $_.Value -eq $line.Subnet -and $_.ShortCode -eq "$Site"
    } | ForEach-Object {
        Remove-CMBoundary -Id $_.BoundaryID } }